# How to get data between a range of dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to select records between the dates:

[image]

If I input BeginDate as 5/Jan/2019 18:40:00 and EndDate as 25/Jan/2019 18:40:00
then both rows must be selected.

Another example... a record's BeginDate and EndDate respectively 1/Jan/2019 and 31/Jan/2019. If I input 5/Jan/2019 and 25/Jan/2019 then that record must be selected.

Think is if I input any dates between the actual Begindate and EndDate of the records that should be selected.

I used between but it selecting the records having the exact date values.

```
BeginDate >= @BeginDate 
and BeginDate <= dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
and (EndDate is null or EndDate> @EndDate)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: @Zhu Parethesis problem.

Comment: What happens if input dates are 4/Jan/2019 and 1/Mar/2019?

Comment: What happens if input dates are 6/Jan/2019 and 1/Mar/2019?

Comment: should fetch both rows but it's not @SalmanA

Comment: Why delete (and sabotage) your other question, @Zhu , and then post this one which has the same (low) amount of detail as the last?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your feedback, you need a simple date overlap query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE @EndDate   > BeginDate
AND   @BeginDate < EndDate
```

It will match the rows where the Start and EndDate intersect @Start and @EndDate in *any* manner. It assumes that end dates are exclusive. You might want to add `(... OR EndDate IS NULL)` to handle null values.

Comment: @larnu I have added clarification. The operator are correct for exclusive end dates i.e. where 2019-02-31 13:41:00 means the event ends _just before_ 13:41:00.